# Sending dbmail with a query result with an okay format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sp-send-dbmail

Im trying create an automated mail with my query results, but the formatting is messed up and it's barely understandable. The query returns 10 columns with aproximately 10 lines. Is there any good way to easily format it better? It doesn't matter if it's an attached file or in the mail body(maybe a .txt file?).

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
@profile_name='Notification', 
@recipients='test@test.com', 
@subject='Updated', 
@body = 'Hi this is an automated mail', 
@query = 'SELECT * FROM [TestDB].[dbo].[TestTable]',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 0
```

Thank you!

Br Andreas

Comment: build html body manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808340/how-can-i-use-sp-send-dbmail-to-send-multiple-queries?rq=1), you can format your body in HTML-style before calling `sp_send_dbmail`. In that case you don't pass the `@query`-parameter but add `@body_format='HTML'`.